# nvm, node etc. paths missing from integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the insiders edition and zsh with ohmyzsh inside iTerm2 on OSX High Sierra.

If I launch the integrated command line in VSCode `echo $path` returns:

```
/Users/username/.yarn/bin:/Users/username/.cargo/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/lldb:
/Users/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/username/.scripts:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Obviously, the node path, nvm path etc. are missing so the terminal is not much use to me.

But typing `echo $path` in my terminal outside of VSCode returns:

```
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/bin /Users/username/.yarn/bin
/Users/username/.cargo/bin /usr/bin /usr/bin/lldb /Users/username/bin
/usr/local/bin /Users/username/.scripts /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin
/sbin /opt/X11/bin
```

Which has all the paths I need for my development activities.

I have this alias in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders" --args $* ;}
```

If I launch code using the alias from an external terminal the node paths are correct.

As far as I can see this is because loading code from the Dock shortcut doesn't load the terminal using my user profile so it loads the profile from `/etc/zprofile` instead, which sets the path using `/usr/libexec/path_helper` so it misses all of my important paths that I need for development.

I suspect that most people would prefer the settings from their user profiles to be used. This would mean all of our dev apps would work from the integrated terminal and also the end of the infamous `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option` error caused by the improper setting of paths.

How can I get VSCode to use the environment of the terminal in my user profile when launched from the Dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings and edit integrated terminal

```
// Object with environment variables that will be added to the VS Code process to be used by the terminal on OS X
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {},
```

there you can pass in your variables

Comment: That works up to a point but it would be great if we could have `terminal.integrated.env.useUserEnv` though. The plumbing is there because that is effectively what we do when launching it from the command line.

Comment: have you tried adding this to your user settings "terminal.explorerKind": "external" ?

Comment: "terminal.explorerKind" just determines whether the right click context menu in the explorer will launch the integrated terminal or the external terminal. I still want to use the integrated terminal... I do feel a pull request coming on though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The vscode docs also offer a solution for the warning `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"`:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/integrated-terminal.md#why-is-nvm-complaining-about-a-prefix-option-when-the-integrated-terminal-is-launched

From the docs:

> This is mostly a macOS problem and does not happen in external
>   terminals. The typical reasons for this are the following:
>
> `npm` was globally installed using another instance of `node` which is
>   somewhere in your path (such as `/usr/local/bin/npm`). In order to get
>   the development tools on the `$PATH`, VS Code will launch a bash login
>   shell on start up. This means that your `~/.bash_profile` has already
>   run and when an Integrated Terminal launches, it will run another
>   login shell, reordering the `$PATH` potentially in unexpected ways. To
>   resolve this issue, you need to track down where the old `npm` is
>   installed and remove both it and its out of date node_modules. You can
>   do this by finding the `nvm` initialization script and running `which npm`
>   before it runs, which should print the path when you launch a new
>   terminal.
>
> Once you have the path to npm, you can find the old node_modules by
>   resolving the symlink by running a command something like this:
>
> `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep npm`
>
> This will give you the resolved path at the end:
>
> `... npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`
>
> From there, removing the files and relaunching VS Code should fix the issue:
>
> `rm -R /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`